# Remove data from sub report that exists in Main Report Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2011

I have the following issue which I'm not sure how to handle.

My main report returns data that exists in my sub report.

I basically need to remove the record from my sub report if it exists in my main report.

e.g

Current results

Main Report- A2,    Sub Report - A1, A2, A3

Desired Results-

Main Report- A2,    Sub Report - A1, A3

Thank you in return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass main report data to sub report using sub report links and then add below condition in sub report `Record selection formula`

```
databasefield not in {pm-mainreportfield} //this is main report link to sub report
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the response. I have managed to pass one main report link to the sub report.  Can these links work on the basis of multiple data passes e.g.  For each row of data populated   in my main report I then start passing all the fields of that row to the sub report to conditionally filter the sub report output. I essentially have multuple criteria that I need to check against per row,

Comment: you can create a array of the data and then pass it to sub report... if not show me the report design will try to help more detail

Comment: NP let me know if you need further assistance